# C++ 'this' argument to member function <function> has type 'const <type>', but function is not marked const

Tags: c++, constants, this

I tried searching everywhere for an explanation to this error, but all I can find is code to some specific codebase. Now I have a couple thousand line codebase, and this error keeps on appearing everywhere (more than 20 of this same error), though everything was functioning correctly a some time ago. I haven't even changed anything in my codebase.

To clarify a bit, all my functions' constant arguments are marked as 'const', almost all return types (except for friend functions) are marked as 'const', and my getter functions are marked 'const'. But the thing is, I don't understand, shouldn't 'const' types act the same as normal types, except that they cannot be altered?

Any good explanation of this error to direct me to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: From the error message, it seems like you're calling a non-const method on a const object. Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: Hard to explain the error in your code without seeing the code. If you want a full explanation of `const` then a C++ book would be the best option.

Comment: @cigien Sure! I have a method: `inline auto length() -> decltype(this->string.length()) const { return this->string.length; }` which I am calling on a 'const' object. Isn't the method `const`? Should the `const` keyword be placed before `-> decltype(...)`?

Comment: Please add that information to the question. Make sure that the error is reproducible.

Comment: `return this->string.length;` is different from `return this->string.length();`

Comment: I just got if fixed when I replied to @cigien. It seems `const -> decltype(...)` is different from `-> decltype(...) const`. All I needed to do is place the `const` keyword before the `->`. Can someone explain this difference?

Comment: @skevelis because after `->` goes the return type. I.e. `auto Foo::foo() -> int const {...}` is the same as `const int Foo::foo() {...}`

Comment: In the former the method is const in the latter its the return type? I'm only guessing.

Comment: @DanM. and @john thank you for your reply. I just checked it and it fixed everything. Should I make my return type `const`?

Comment: @skevelis No. There are no advantages to that (note, that it doesn't concern pointer/reference _to_ const).